# Cannot convert value of type '(Data?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> ()'

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I created a function to retrieve json data from a network server.  It works properly when run in a production environment but when it's setup to be unit-tested the error : `Cannot convert value of type '(Data?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> ()'`. Here is the function:

```
func getJSONData <T : Codable> (url: ServerUrl, type: T.Type, completionHandler:@escaping (_ details: T) -> ())  {

    guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + url.rawValue) else { return }


    session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, err) in

        guard err == nil else {
        print("There was a network error:", err as Any)
        return
        }
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            let updatedModels = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            completionHandler(updatedModels)

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            return }

        }).resume()
}
```

Here it is in the unit test:

```
func test_getJSONData_should_return_data() {

var actualData: Data?

sut.getJSONData(url: ServerUrl.colors, type: MainColor.self, completionHandler: { (data) in //error here

    actualData = data

})
XCTAssertNotNil(actualData)
```

}

Comment: What's `MainColor`? Is it `Codable`? `data` in your closure will be of type `MainColor`, which you can't assign to `Data`, and is non-optional, so testing for `nil` won't do anything useful.

Comment: This is true, changed Data to MainColor worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that completion returns value of type `MainColor` not `Data` , this should be

```
var actualData: MainColor?
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: @SwiftyJD Please accept the answer if it solved your problem, thanks